# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `urce' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue

Tags: mysql, gem, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Web App Development beginning with Ruby On Rails. To get started I followed [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04).

I'm in the final steps where it asks to create a Database (I'm using mysql) by running `rake db:create` but I get the following error.
[image]

Below I have pasted my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files. Please advice if you need anything else.

urce 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

## We need a newish Rake since Active Job sets its test tasks' descriptions.

gem 'rake', '>= 10.3'

## Active Job depends on the URI::GID::MissingModelIDError, which isn't released yet.

gem 'globalid', github: 'rails/globalid', branch: 'master'
gem 'rack', github: 'rack/rack', branch: 'master'

## This needs to be with require false as it is

## loaded after loading the test library to

## ensure correct loading order

gem 'mocha', '~> 0.14', require: false

gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', github: 'rails/jquery-rails', branch: 'master'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'arel', github: 'rails/arel', branch: 'master'
gem 'mail', github: 'mikel/mail', branch: 'master'

gem 'sprockets', github: 'rails/sprockets', branch: 'master'
gem 'sprockets-rails', github: 'rails/sprockets-rails', branch: 'master'
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: 'master'

## require: false so bcrypt is loaded only when has_secure_password is used.

## This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework)

## being dependent on a binary library.

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10', require: false

## This needs to be with require false to avoid

## it being automatically loaded by sprockets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0', require: false
gem 'sass', '>= 3.3', require: false

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
  gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.3', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'w3c_validators'
  gem 'kindlerb', '0.1.1'
end

## ActiveSupport

gem 'dalli', '>= 2.2.1'

## ActiveJob

group :job do
  gem 'resque', require: false
  gem 'resque-scheduler', require: false
  gem 'sidekiq', require: false
  gem 'sucker_punch', require: false
  gem 'delayed_job', require: false
  gem 'queue_classic', github: "QueueClassic/queue_classic", branch: 'master', require: false, platforms: :ruby
  gem 'sneakers', require: false
  gem 'que', require: false
  gem 'backburner', require: false
  gem 'qu-rails', github: "bkeepers/qu", branch: "master", require: false
  gem 'qu-redis', require: false
  gem 'delayed_job_active_record', require: false
  gem 'sequel', require: false
end

## Add your own local bundler stuff

local_gemfile = File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/.Gemfile"
instance_eval File.read local_gemfile if File.exist? local_gemfile

group :test do
  # FIX: Our test suite isn't ready to run in random order yet
  gem 'minitest', '< 5.3.4'

platforms :mri do
    gem 'stackprof'
    gem 'byebug'
  end

gem 'benchmark-ips'
end

platforms :ruby do
  gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.4.5'

# Needed for compiling the ActionDispatch::Journey parser
  gem 'racc', '>=1.4.6', require: false

# ActiveRecord
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

group :db do
    gem 'pg', '>= 0.18.0'
    gem 'mysql', '>= 2.9.0'
    gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.0', github: 'brianmario/mysql2'
  end
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'json'
  if ENV['AR_JDBC']
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', github: 'jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter', branch: 'master'
    group :db do
      gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', github: 'jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter', branch: 'master'
      gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', github: 'jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter', branch: 'master'
    end
  else
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '>= 1.3.0'
    group :db do
      gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', '>= 1.3.0'
      gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '>= 1.3.0'
    end
  end
end

platforms :rbx do
  # The rubysl-yaml gem doesn't ship with Psych by default
  # as it needs libyaml that isn't always available.
  gem 'psych', '~> 2.0'
end

## gems that are necessary for ActiveRecord tests with Oracle database

if ENV['ORACLE_ENHANCED']
  platforms :ruby do
    gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1'
  end
  gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', github: 'rsim/oracle-enhanced', branch: 'master'
end

## A gem necessary for ActiveRecord tests with IBM DB

gem 'ibm_db' if ENV['IBM_DB']

```
GEMFILE.lock
```

remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.4)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (8.2.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.99)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.3)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.4.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activerecord (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.4)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.4.20)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.6.1)
    sprockets (3.5.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mysql2
  rails (= 4.2.4)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Ruby version 2.2.3 and installed 2.2.4, which sorted the issue!